# INT 10H function 06H moves the cursor

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I run the following assembly code on `(emu8086)`:

```
clearScr macro
         mov ah, 06h
         mov al, 00h
         mov bh, 71h
         mov cx, 0000h
         mov dx, 184fh
         int 10h
clearScr endm

print macro string
    mov ah, 09h    
    lea dx, string
    int 21h        
print endm

.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    msg    db 'Hello, world!', '$'  
    nl     db 0AH, 0DH, '$' 
    myname db 'Ahmed', '$'

.code                   
    main    proc
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax

        print myname
        clearScr
        print msg

        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
    main    endp
```

and the `clearScr` macro seems to be moving the cursor as the final text printed on the screen isn't starting from the corner.[image: figure 0]

Why is this happening? I'm not trying to set/move the cursor.

Comment: `int 10h` function `06h` is just "scroll up window", so you need to reset the cursor position as well, to the first column.

Comment: @lurker it is already by default set to the first column. Here it moves forward and my question is why

Comment: "default set to the first column"  - What makes you think so?  I see you print `Ahmed`, but you don't do a cr/lf afterwords.  Wouldn't that mean you're positioned at column 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and the `clearScr` macro seems to be moving the cursor

It is exactly the opposite:

`clearScr` is **not** moving the cursor but you want it to be moved.

What happens is the following:

- `print myname` will move the cursor; the cursor will no longer be located in the top left corner but it will be located at the end of your name.
- If I understood correctly, `clearScr` will clear the screen but **not** change the cursor position; this means that the cursor will **remain** in the position where it was **after** `print myname`
- `print msg` will also not change the cursor position before printing the message, so the message will be printed to the position where the cursor was after `print myname`

If you want to clear the screen **and** to move the cursor to the corner, you will have to do **two** steps:

- Clear the screen (this will **not** move the cursor to the corner)
- Move the cursor to the corner (for example with `int 10h` function `AH=2`)

> I see you print `Ahmed`, but you don't do a cr/lf afterwords.

If I understand correctly, printing CR/LF would cause the text to be printed in the second line after clearing the screen.

Printing CR only would move the cursor to the top left corner **if** the cursor is in already the top line.

Comment: "printing CR/LF would cause the text to be printed in the second line" - Huh?  If you print "Ahmed", then your cursor position is 6.  If you print "Ahmed\r\n", then your cursor position is 1.  If your cursor position is 6 and you scroll the screen up (which is what `ah=06` does), then your cursor position is still 6.  If your cursor position is 1 and you scroll, your cursor position is still 1.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd You print "Ahmed" and the cursor position is (column,row)=(6,1). You print "\r\n" and the cursor position is (1,2). As far as I understood, `ah=6` does not change the cursor position, so the cursor position is still (1,2). But the corner would be (1,1).

Comment: I get it now, that was very clear thanks a lot :+1: